# Fetch out of sequence error on Oracle for join select query, intermittent

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

For the below left outer join, my Java application sometimes receives a fetch out of sequence error:

"JDBC error reported: (SQLState = HY010) - java.sql.SQLException: [tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence "

After cycling the Oracle server, the issue seems to go away for a little while, but is back only days later. For every 100 time this query runs, it might produce 20 fetch out of sequence errors. I haven't been able to reproduce it manual, like by running the query from SQL Developer.

I'm not sure what the issue is because the application isn't updating or inserting into these tables. The query runs only after the table is populated, and only one instance of the application runs, sequentially. I'm also not using any PL/SQL. Everything I read about this error results from select-into statements and misuse of cursors. I'm not using either.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong here?

Thanks

```
select r.report_key, r.total, r.custom11, r.custom12, r.C_DATE, r.ORG_UNIT3, sum(j.journal_amount), j.ACCOUNT_CODE, 
j.PAYER_NAME, re.posted_amount, re.ENTRY_ID, re.custom39, re.custom40, av.POSTED_AMT, av.TAX_AMT, 
e.FOREIGN_OR_DOMESTIC, em.EMP_ID, r.custom9, re.description 
from report r 
left outer join journal j on r.REPORT_KEY = j.REPORT_KEY and r.SEQUENCENUMBER = j.SEQUENCENUMBER
left outer join report_entry re on r.REPORT_KEY = re.REPORT_KEY and r.SEQUENCENUMBER = re.SEQUENCENUMBER
left outer join ENTRY_LOCATION e on r.REPORT_KEY = e.REPORT_KEY and r.SEQUENCENUMBER = e.SEQUENCENUMBER
left outer join EMPLOYEE em on r.REPORT_KEY = em.REPORT_KEY and r.SEQUENCENUMBER = em.SEQUENCENUMBER
left outer join VAT_TAX av on r.REPORT_KEY = av.REPORT_KEY and r.SEQUENCENUMBER = av.SEQUENCENUMBER
where r.batchid = ? and r.report_key = ? and j.ACCOUNT_CODE != 'CASHADV' 
group by r.report_key, r.total, r.custom11, r.custom12, r.C_DATE, r.ORG_UNIT3, j.ACCOUNT_CODE, 
j.PAYER_NAME, re.posted_amount, re.ENTRY_ID, re.custom39, re.custom40, av.POSTED_AMT, av.TAX_AMT,  
e.FOREIGN_OR_DOMESTIC, em.EMP_ID, r.custom9, re.description
```

Comment: ORA-01022 is not a problem with a select statement but with the code which calls it. You need to post the Java.

Comment: The trouble is, I'm handing the query to a proprietary Java application (Tibco Business Works), so I have no idea how it's being used.

Comment: Maybe you need to take this up with the vendor. Assuming your organisation has a support contract